Proper Code For Mobile Caching in htaccess file
I have a wordpress site and to speed it up I'm using a caching plugin. Unfortunately the free version does not have mobile cache option in it. So from another installation I found out this code which is almost 4-5 years old. Yes this code was working well. I just would like to know if this code still work today on mobiles with latest OS (Android, Mac)? Here it is:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*\bCrMo\b|CriOS|Android.*Chrome\/[.0-9]*\s(Mobile)?|\bDolfin\b|Opera.*Mini|Opera.*Mobi|Android.*Opera|Mobile.*OPR\/[0-9.]+|Coast\/[0-9.]+|Skyfire|Mobile\sSafari\/[.0-9]*\sEdge|IEMobile|MSIEMobile|fennec|firefox.*maemo|(Mobile|Tablet).*Firefox|Firefox.*Mobile|FxiOS|bolt|teashark|Blazer|Version.*Mobile.*Safari|Safari.*Mobile|MobileSafari|Tizen|UC.*Browser|UCWEB|baiduboxapp|baidubrowser|DiigoBrowser|Puffin|\bMercury\b|Obigo|NF-Browser|NokiaBrowser|OviBrowser|OneBrowser|TwonkyBeamBrowser|SEMC.*Browser|FlyFlow|Minimo|NetFront|Novarra-Vision|MQQBrowser|MicroMessenger|Android.*PaleMoon|Mobile.*PaleMoon|Android|blackberry|\bBB10\b|rim\stablet\sos|PalmOS|avantgo|blazer|elaine|hiptop|palm|plucker|xiino|Symbian|SymbOS|Series60|Series40|SYB-[0-9]+|\bS60\b|Windows\sCE.*(PPC|Smartphone|Mobile|[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3})|Window\sMobile|Windows\sPhone\s[0-9.]+|WCE;|Windows\sPhone\s10.0|Windows\sPhone\s8.1|Windows\sPhone\s8.0|Windows\sPhone\sOS|XBLWP7|ZuneWP7|Windows\sNT\s6\.[23]\;\sARM\;|\biPhone.*Mobile|\biPod|\biPad|Apple-iPhone7C2|MeeGo|Maemo|J2ME\/|\bMIDP\b|\bCLDC\b|webOS|hpwOS|\bBada\b|BREW.*$ [NC]

I also would like to know what is the meaning of [0-9] in these lines. Does it means the version of software version like Android 9, 10 etc...
Sorry Guys, I don't know much about caching rules in .htaccess file. I'm on a Litespeed server (Apache Version:2.4.62)
Tried to add this code into .htaccess file but unsure about its effectiveness in caching environment.
